# SQL: Split Column Values into two Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table tbl1

How can I split the column values by 10 (number of characters)

FROM:

```
Column1            
Butuan City Philippines
Zamboanga City Philippines
Manila City Philippines
```

TO:

```
Column1           Column2
Butuan Cit        y Philippines
Zamboanga         City Philippines
Manila Cit        y Philippines
```

Comment: You want y in column 2??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `SUBSTRING()` function:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Column1, 1, 10) AS Column1,
    SUBSTRING(Column1, 11, LEN(Column1) - 10) AS Column2
FROM yourtable
```

Note that we do not have to worry about using indices in substring which are greater than the length of `Column1`, q.v. the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/ms187748.aspx) which states:

> If start [second parameter] is greater than the number of characters in the value expression, a zero-length expression is returned.

and

> If the sum of start and length is greater than the number of characters in expression, the whole value expression beginning at start is returned.

Comment: If you give a static length, it won't give error if the column value length increases?? Like if column value is 'Llanfairpwllgwyngyll'

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me, but I believe my answer will work, without the need of resorting to `LEFT()` or any helper functions other than `SUBSTRING()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT` and `SUBSTRING` string functions. Try this

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(100) = 'Zamboanga City Philippines'

SELECT LEFT (( @str ), 10),
       Substring (( @str ), 10 + 1, Len(@str))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LEFT`, `LEN`, and `SUBSTRING`

```
SELECT LEFT(Column1,10) AS 'Column1'

SELECT SUBSTRING(Column1, LEN(LEFT(Column1,10)) + 1, LEN(Column1)) AS 'Column2'
```

**Merge the two queries:**

```
SELECT LEFT(Column1,10) AS 'Column1', 
       SUBSTRING(Column1, LEN(LEFT(Column1,10)) + 1, LEN(Column1)) AS 'Column2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the in-build [SUBSTRING()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187748.aspx) function of SQL to achieve your expected result.

For E.g.

```
IF (LEN(Column1) > 10)
BEGIN
    SELECT SUBSTRING(Column1, 1, 10) AS Column1,SUBSTRING(Column1, 11, LEN(Column1) - 10) AS Column2
    FROM <TABLE>
END
```